# How do I use Blob to create a PDF in my apex controller and use it in my Lightning Component without using VisualForce Pages?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, controller, blob

**This is  the apex controller:**

```
    public class pdfGenerate {

        public static final Integer limitRecords = 10;
        @AuraEnabled
        public static Blob generatePdf(){

            List<Account> records = [SELECT ID, Name, AccountNumber, Match_Billing_Address__c FROM Account LIMIT :limitRecords];
            String pdfText;
            pdfText = '<HTML><BODY>';
            pdfText = pdfText + '<H2>Account Records in PDF</H2>';
            //pdfText
            for(Integer i=0; i<limitRecords; i++){

                pdfText = pdfText +('<p>' + records.get(i).ID + '<&emsp>' + records.get(i).Name + '<&emsp>' 
                                    + records.get(i).AccountNumber + '<&emsp>'+ records.get(i).Match_Billing_Address__c + '<\br></p>');
            }
            pdfText = pdfText + '</BODY></HTML>';
            System.debug(pdfText);


            Blob pdfContent = Blob.toPdf(pdfText);
            System.debug(pdfContent);
            return pdfContent;
        }

    }
```

**This is the client side controller:**

```
({
    initHandler : function(component, event, helper) { 

        var action = component.get(component.get('c.generatePdf'));

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            if (response.getState() == 'SUCCESS') {
                var templateData = response.getReturnValue();
                console.log(templateData);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    },

})
```

The component and the client-side controller part is where I'm stuck. I don't know how to go about it now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to display this blob inside your component?

Comment: Do you want to display the PDF in the lightning component or giving the option to save the pdf file?

Comment: I need to display it in a lightning component. But I wouldn't mind adding the functionality of saving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PDF.JS Library for this, please follow [link](https://medium.com/my-journey-with-salesforce1-platform/pdf-viewer-lightning-component-f96e6a5704ab) for details.
Find Git repository for code [here](https://github.com/kumarrk21/PDFViewer).

Brief:

You can download this component from this github repo. Use the ‘Deploy to Salesforce button’ in the repo to deploy to your org. Once deployed, go to /auradocs/reference.app->components->c->pdfViewer to go through the documentation on the usage of this component. There is also an example component named `pdfViewerExampleComponent` provided as a part of the documentation. This component takes the PDF data in base64 format and displays it in the viewer.

You need to make changes in your controller as below
basically change return type to string and convert your blob to base64 encoded string.

```
    public class pdfGenerate {

    public static final Integer limitRecords = 10;
        @AuraEnabled
        public static String generatePdf(){

            List<Account> records = [SELECT ID, Name, AccountNumber, Match_Billing_Address__c FROM Account LIMIT :limitRecords];
            String pdfText;
            pdfText = '<HTML><BODY>';
            pdfText = pdfText + '<H2>Account Records in PDF</H2>';
            //pdfText
            for(Integer i=0; i<limitRecords; i++){

                pdfText = pdfText +('<p>' + records.get(i).ID + '<&emsp>' + records.get(i).Name + '<&emsp>' 
                                    + records.get(i).AccountNumber + '<&emsp>'+ records.get(i).Match_Billing_Address__c + '<\br></p>');
            }
            pdfText = pdfText + '</BODY></HTML>';
            System.debug(pdfText);


            Blob pdfContent = Blob.toPdf(pdfText);
            System.debug(pdfContent);
            return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(pdfContent);
    }

}
```

Comment: You could have provided some more details like the approach some code snippets etc. Link only answer will not be helpful to somebody in future if the links will die.

Comment: @SarojBera thanks for the suggestion! I have added brief about how to use it

Comment: Actually I am using an apex controller to get records from my Account object as a blob. I want to use this in my js controller to display these records in that pdf format..

Comment: So first you need to install package from the link into your org, then all of the required components will be created in your org, there is a component named `pdfViewerExampleComponent` if you open its controller, on line no 3 there is variable named `pdfData`, it has some hard coded value, you need to assign output from your apex controller to this variable.

Comment: better to try this in developer edition/sandbox org first.

Comment: @vedantgupta please check updated answer

Comment: Thank You. I was able to make it work. Now I'm trying to do it without using this library. I don't know if it's possible to generate a pdf in the lightning component client-side controller but I'll still try. If anyone of you knows  a way, you're most welcome to share it. @rahulgawale